# vim netrw ftp bookmarks

Tags: vim, macvim, netrw

I almost always work remotely, so i've been using netrw to work over ftp. I can set bookmarks, query bookmarks and even delete them... but i can't actually go to bookmarks

ie. {cnt}gb
throws this error:

E121: Undefined variable: b:netrw_cur
E116: Invalid arguments for function 21_NetrwBookHistHandler

[ macvim snapshot 55 on osx 10.6.5 ]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this problem when using v143c of netrw; you may get that version from http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW (I'm using Scientific Linux).  And, netrw is now up to v151f.